# Is it possible to increase the length of Name field in Custom Setting

Tags: customsetting

I am passing dynamic values to the getValues() method so I didn't have control of what is being entered, whenever name string crosses 38 characters its giving "Custom Setting Name too long" error.

So, is it possible to increase the length of Custom setting Name field?

Answer (score 3):

That is the limit for the custom setting name. Please, take a look to this article where it explains this limitation:

[Define Custom Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cs_define.htm&type=5)

[image]

Looking around I found that there is a 'workaround' that it may help you.
Check it [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Rq4hAAC)